# aggregate dataframe by more than one type in R

Tags: r

I am aggregating a dataframe using the aggregate function in R. I can get the means of each column aggregated on date and id easily like this:

```
aggregate(dataframe, by=list(dataframe$date, dataframe$id), FUN=mean, na.rm=TRUE)
```

How can I aggregate some columns as means and others as sums?

Comment: Use two different calls. `aggregate` applies the same function to each non-group column. Or use `split` and `lapply` a custom function. There must be tons of worked examples on SO by no that use this strategy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `summaryBy` function from the `doBy` package could help where you can provide multiple functions:

```
require(doBy)
summaryBy(list("date", "id"), data = dataframe, FUN = c(mean, sum), na.rm=TRUE)
```

If you want specific columns to have a specific function, the `data.table` package probably makes it the easiest.

```
require(data.table)
dt <- data.table(data.frame)

# set "V1" and "V2" ... "VX" to whichever columns you are interested in
dt.out <- dt[, list(s.v1=sum(V1), m.v2=mean(V2)),
             by=c("date", "id")]
```

Comment: this looks interesting...but how can we specify which column gets which function?

Comment: @Cybernetic, you can use `data.table` package to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Using your code, one straight forward way is to

```
res1 <- aggregate(dataframe, by=list(dataframe$date, dataframe$id), FUN=mean, na.rm=TRUE)
```

and

```
res2 <- aggregate(dataframe, by=list(dataframe$date, dataframe$id), FUN=sum, na.rm=TRUE)
```

and then

```
res <- cbind(res1,res2)
```

Now ***res*** contains mean and sum results, you can choose whatever column you need.